# RegEx valid relative urls in href and src links of html

Tags: html, regex

I have this RegEx and have tested it against the below dataset:

RegEx: `/(href|src)\=\"(?!(ht|f)tp|www|:|\/\/)(\/)?/g`

Dataset:

```
href="/hello
href="hello/bob
href="new/hello/bob
href="hello/test.com/hello
href="abc.hello.com/hello <-- I want to exclude this type of url
href="www.google.com/hello
href="https://www.google.com
href="http://google.com
href="ftp://www.google.com
href="://google.com
href="//google.com
```

Here is a demo link with the above inputs:
https://regex101.com/r/1mCFWL/4

The issue I am having is that the 4th test item `abc.hello.com/hello` also matches the RegEx and I would like to exclude all URLs which contain a `.com` before a `/`.

I am trying to do a lookup ahead but have been unable to get this working.
Can anyone help improve the above RegEx to add support to exclude URLs which contain a `.com` before a `/`?

**EDIT**:
A successful match criterion is matching only the first 4 items in the dataset.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/1mCFWL/3, the`[^"]*\.com` alternative can be added to the lookahead.

Comment: Could you specify what the successful match criteria is?

Comment: @AleksWI updated the question with the successful match criteria.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your answer! how would I stop the lookup when it hits a /? With your example the url is invalid even if it comes after the first /. So for example this would be invalid, and it should be valid. href="hello/test.com/hello

Comment: Add `/` to the negated character class, `[^"\/]*\.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add `[^"\/]*\.com` or `[^"\/]*\.com(?![^\/])` alternative to the negative lookahead:

```
(?:href|src)="(?!(?:ht|f)tp|www|:|\/\/|[^"\/]*\.com)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1mCFWL/5) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3Ahref%7Csrc)%3D%22(%3F!(%3F%3Aht%7Cf)tp%7Cwww%7C%3A%7C%5C%2F%5C%2F%7C%5B%5E%22%5C%2F%5D*%5C.com)):

[image]

The `(?![^\/])` will require `/` or end of string if you add that pattern after `com`.